# WxWidgets Application Run Failed

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

After hours i was finally able to compile the wxwidgets-2.8.12 library as follows:-

I unzipped the .zip into a folder D:\wxwidgets2812\wxwidgets-2.8.12

I went in D:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0 run the batch file and did the following:-

Went to the following path:-

```
 cd /d/{WXWIN}/build/msw
```

and compiled the library in the following way as :-

```
 mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc MONOLITHIC=0 SHARED=1 UNICODE=0 BUILD=release
```

It Build /Compiled succesfully Then I added in the project properties ->include directories ->D:\wxwidgets2812\wxwidgets-2.8.12\include ,addidtional options->`wx-config --cxxflags`,in linker i added in libraries->`wx-config --libs`

```
  Now when i run my code / project ,it gives me following errors:-

 The application failed with exit code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). 
 This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH. 
 Please try to start the following command from the command shell (cmd.exe). 
 This may give some additional information. 

 C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_6\dist\Debug\MinGW_1-    
 Windows\cppapplication_6 

 RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,515, total time: 22ms)
```

Please help me running the application.
Thanks

Comment: Why not go for wxWidgets 2.9.x. And since you are on windows, i would suggest Visual Studio. This will make your job simpler. This can help http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH"

This suggests that you have built your application to link to a DLL containing the wxWidgets library.

You can go two ways from here:

1. Change your application build to link statically to the library.  You will also have to build wxWidgets to generate a static library if you have not already done so.
2. Copy the wxWidgets DLL into your path. ( Or add the DLL folder to your path as a quick fix to get you started. )

Option #2 is probably simpler for now, since you seem to have built the DLL version of wxWidgets.  So, you need to find the wxWidgets DLL that was created when you built wxWidgets and move it into your path.

Comment: Statically you mean i need to recompile the wxwidgets doing a static build (SHARED=0) is that what it means

2.Copy the wxwidgets DLL into your path ->not clear which DLL are you Pointing to.

Comment: I have got a path as D:\wxwidgets\wxwidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\msw
under gcc_dll there are 10 dlls,as far as i an understand you mean that i need to add "D:\wxwidgets\wxwidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\"in the path variable

Comment: Adding to your path would be simplest to get you started.  If you decide to continue using DLLs, you should consider the monolithic build.

Comment: All though i tried with a MONOLITHIC Build as well but the problem is it failed at the last saying Memory exhausted, returned 1 exit alue so i didnt approach with if you have anything that can get me rid of it except for installing tdm gcc i would appreciate that , i still didnt get you on adding the path can you please elaborate as what i need to do on this.

Comment: There are several ways to add the DLL libraries to your path.  The simplest to explain is to copy the library files ( *.dll ) to the working folder where your application runs.